# Sidebar and Main page persistence - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, navigation

I am using a sidebar that searches and generates a list (within the sidebar) I want the main page to remain unchanged when searching with the sidebar. I believe this requires some JS, but I know nothing about JS.

- my navbar is in a div _navbar.html.erb
- main page is basically any other page being generated

here is my code: https://github.com/nrkfeller/ratingapplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AJAX with rails. Here is how it may work for you:

1. Add a  **:remote => true** to your form and **:'data-update-target' => 'update-container'** to specify where you want the search results to go. You might want to avoid using the courses_path, but use `form_tag({:controller => courses, :action => 'search'}` to directly state where you want the form to be submitted.

   `<%= form_tag courses_path, method: :get,  :remote => true ,class: "navbar-  form navbar-right", :'data-update-target' => 'update-container' , role: "search" do %>
                     <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search",:disable_with => 'Please wait...', name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
                     </p>
      <% end %>`
2. Add this to your sidebar. This is where the partial with the results will come:

   ```
     <div id="update-container"></div>
   ```
3. Add the javascript`` to put it where it is supposed to be when the request finishes:

   `<script>
     $(function() {
     $('form[data-update-target]').on('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
     var target = $(this).data('update-target');
     $('#' + target).html(data);
     });
   });`
4. Add a partial named `_search_results.html.erb` <- this is where your results go.

   `<!-- arbitrary code -->
      <%=  @results.each do |result| %>
      <%= result %>`
5. In your controller:

   `def search
       @results= #your search code 
      render :partial => 'search_results', :content_type => 'text/html'
     end`

This is will get the functionality you wanted. Beware, this is more of a *pesudocode* than an exact implementation of what you want to do. You have to fill in the gaps.

I hope I was helpful!